# Alternative for the word "options" as in "extra purchase possibilities to go with a booking"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms, hypernyms

Is there a better alternative to the word *options* when referring to "extra purchase possibilities next to a booking you have already made"? For instance, you can think of food and beverages, audiovisual equipment and parking spots.

I think the word *options* in that context is a bit too vague, since it also refers to options on a stock exchange or choices one can make.

I was thinking about *add-ons*, or *items*. Do these suit better? Is there a more apt word still?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please note that an "@RegDwighr" won't ping me (just use "@Reg"), and no ping at all will work if it's in a comment thread I haven't participated in (so either find a comment of mine to reply to directly, or just flag the question for mod attention instead). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

*Extras*.

If they are optional "added value" features on top of a core item, that's the usual name.

Answer (score 0):

In many contexts, you can use *choices*.

Comment: Thanks for the replies already Barrie & SF. It will often be used in a context like: "you can add extras/ options/ add-ons to your booking via this button. Personally I think "You can add choices via this button" sounds good.. Do you?

Comment: Additional Items ...may be sufficient.